# innodb query taking very long, but appears to be done correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Been trying for awhile now to get this figured out.  Basically all I am doing is returning counts for various tables and/or conditions in those tables.

As it stands this is taking about 13s to run.  The entire DB is only 700KiB so there is hardly any date in there which concerns me even more.  Using dbForge to view the plan, profile, etc it appears to be working properly, however, why the heck is it taking this long?  Sometimes it is quick and others it is extremely slow... other times it errors out with the following :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:126 Incorrect key file for table
>   '/tmp/#sql_5c99_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Majority of the time spent, when it does work is, from 'Copying to tmp table on disk'.  Can someone help me out here and explain why this does not work as expected?

**Query :**

```
SELECT
  users.user_id as DT_RowId,
  users.username as username,
  computers.computer_name as computer_name,
  count(distinct log1.activity_id) as log1s,
  count(distinct log2.activity_id) as log2s,
  count(distinct log3.activity_id) as log3s,
  count(distinct log4.activity_id) as log4s,
  count(distinct log5.activity_id) as log5s,
  count(distinct log6.activity_id) as log6s,
  count(distinct log7.activity_id) as log7s,
  count(distinct log8.activity_id) as log8s,
  count(distinct log9.activity_id) as log9s,
  count(distinct log10.activity_id) as log10s,
  count(distinct log11.activity_id) as log11s

FROM computers

INNER JOIN users
    on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id

LEFT JOIN log1
    on log1.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log2
    on log2.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log3
    on log3.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log4
    on log4.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN log5
    on log5.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log6
    on log6.user_id = users.user_id AND log6.event_title = 'test1'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log7
    on log7.user_id = users.user_id AND log7.event_title = 'test2'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log8
    on log8.user_id = users.user_id AND log8.event_title = 'test3'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log9
    on log9.user_id = users.user_id AND log9.event_title = 'test4'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log10
    on log10.user_id = users.user_id AND log10.event_title = 'test5'

LEFT JOIN realtime_logs AS log11
    on log11.user_id = users.user_id AND log11.event_title = 'test6'

WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status

GROUP BY users.user_id
```

**Plan :**

```
computers   1   SIMPLE  ref PRIMARY,unique_filter,status    unique_filter   4   const   5   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
users   1   SIMPLE  ref unique_filter   unique_filter   4   stephen_inno.computers.computer_id  1   Using index
log1    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log2    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log3    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log4    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log5    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 4   stephen_inno.users.user_id  1   Using index
log6    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log7    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log8    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log9    1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log10   1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
log11   1   SIMPLE  ref user_id user_id 771 stephen_inno.users.user_id,const    3   Using index
```

**Profile :**

```
Copying to tmp table on disk    9.911206    71.86
Sorting result  2.566939    18.61
Sending data    1.055551    7.65
removing tmp table  0.170641    1.24
Copying to tmp table    0.051054    0.37
converting HEAP to MyISAM   0.036204    0.26
Creating tmp table  0.000195    0.00
starting    0.000182    0.00
freeing items   0.000167    0.00
statistics  0.000167    0.00
init    0.000080    0.00
preparing   0.000055    0.00
checking permissions    0.000048    0.00
Opening tables  0.000042    0.00
optimizing  0.000033    0.00
end 0.000023    0.00
Table lock  0.000012    0.00
System lock 0.000008    0.00
logging slow query  0.000006    0.00
cleaning up 0.000006    0.00
query end   0.000004    0.00
executing   0.000004    0.00
```

**the result :**

```
DT_Row Id   username    computer_name   log1    log2    log3    log4    log5    log6    log7    log8    log9    log10   log11
17  testuser    COMPUTER_1  0   2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   2
22  testuser2   COMPUTER_2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  testuser3   COMPUTER_2  0   0   0   0   0   68  12  12  0   0   6
```

As you can see 13 seconds for to return just this is pretty bad.

**Additional Info :**

I should add that these same results happen on two different servers... one with MySQL 5.1 and the other with 5.6.  The query looks good to me, the indexes look good, the plan looks good... I just have no idea why this is taking soo long to execute and on a very very small dataset right now.

Comment: `.MYI` is not an innodb file. You mixed MyISAM tables into your query somehow.

Comment: @Ambrish - there's EXPLAIN plan being posted... read it.

Comment: Yes, the explain was posted.  The MYI error no longer appears, and I believe that was indeed due to a mixup with exactly that which has been fixed.  I just ran this again in dbForge and it took 70 seconds to return... same exact query, data, and result.

Comment: You have a very slow hard disk obviously, it might even be dying. I'd check for `innodb_buffer_pool` variable and adjust the size, if you're running with the default setting (8MB). I'd also ensure that tables I work with aren't MyISAM (convert them to InnoDB).

Comment: Everything is innodb right now, but the problem is still there.  I have played with the buffer pool, restarting MySQL afterwards, and the results are the same.

Comment: Can you check what's the I/O usage of your disk? Do you have any programs running that might be abusing your hdd? Is it a mechanical drive or an SSD? If it's a mechanical drive, is it an old one?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know except I have had zero issues with anything prior to this.  It is a dedicated with whm/cpanel/centos about 2 years or so old.

Comment: Check the query behaviour on a different computer (your home/local one) with the same software. If it behaves better, then it's your server's HDD. I'd check if there are any programs using the disk while you run your query, or if the disk is going bad.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... am I right that the explain looks good and I am not going crazy here thinking it is something else?  I see what you mean about the HDD, but the same results happen on two different servers.

Comment: You're not crazy, it looks perfectly fine (to me) and I see no reason for query taking so much time. It does copy to disk, and that takes time so it means the disk must be either doing something or simply being on the verge of dying.

Comment: Could my.cnf settings have any bearing on this issue?